# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' when calling an API service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I deployed an application. But when I tried to call an API service, it shows an error like this:

> 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

But we are using that application till yesterday. No issue was reported. What would be the possible reasons behind this issue?

I saw many answers for this issue. Since the application is in production, can I deploy version 4.0.0.0 or change the web config?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using [fusion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to check what libraries are being loaded, also you can check from your csproj file if there right version is declared in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem in multiple different projects (always in local). Here is the steps that can help me fix the problem.

- It could be a problem with your NuGet packages - make sure that the file `System.Web.Mvc.dll` file can be found in the `packages` folder at the root of your project if you can't find it, backup the `packages` folder, delete it and then right-click the solution name in Visual Studio and "restore packages"
- Or the files may not be copied to the execution folder. Go to `yourSolution/yourProject/bin` and look for `System.Web.Mvc.dll` - If the file is not in the `bin` folder, try to clean-rebuild your solution. If still not, try to copy/paste it manually (from the `packages` folder for example, or any other source)
- Try to upgrade/downgrade the the library in the NuGet package manager

Since your problem occurs on a prod environment, I guess these answer might not help but it may give you a trail to follow :-/